# bar3 colour depending on zdata

Tags: matlab, colors, plot, customization, histogram

When using the [`bar3` function](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html), the colours of the bars depend on the column or row the data is in. Example:

```
data = peaks(20);
bar3(data);
view(-135,30)
```

[image: bar3 example]

How can I make it that the colour of each bar only depends on the height (zdata) of that bar?

Comment: The default behavior is silly, for sure: in what world would you want your data colored by the value of one of the independent variables?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is quite difficult to mess around with the colours of the bars, as all the bars are constructed with patches. You'll have to change the zdata of the vertices of the patches; since this is not very straightforward, I've made a function just for this purpose: [bar3c](https://github.com/GuntherStruyf/matlab-tools/blob/master/bar3c.m)

Example:

```
data = peaks(20);
bar3c(data);
view(-135,30)
```

[image: bar3c example]

### Edit

If you want to use other colors, simply change the [colormap](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html).
If you want to set a whole range to get one same color instead of getting a gradient between your min/max values, you'll have to change the call to `makecdata`. Now it uses the `zdata` to specify its color, you can easily change that to give a range a specific color.

Actually, I just did that and the result can be found [here](https://github.com/GuntherStruyf/matlab-tools/blob/master/bar3crange.m).

Example:

```
data = peaks(20);
bar3crange([-8 0 3 4 8], data);
% colormap: red/yellow/green/blue
colormap([1 0 0;1 1 0;0 1 0;0 0 1]);
view(-135,30);
```

[image: bar3crange example]

Comment: It works. The official instructions, however, fail, as shown in http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/color-3-d-bars-by-height-1.html.

Comment: @InmanLee because that example is intended for R2014a; in R2012a you can use the manual [get](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/get.html) and [set](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/set.html) functions, which give something equal to the example you provided. My [bar3c](https://github.com/GuntherStruyf/matlab-tools/blob/master/bar3c.m) function is different from that as it turns the whole bar the same color, and not only the top side or a shaded bar.

Comment: Nice function. Sometimes having the bars in a single color completely is much better than a shaded version.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you want to do it without external functions, try

```
data = peaks(20);
h = bar3(data);
view(-135,30);


for i = 1:size(data,2)
    cdata = get(h(i),'cdata');
    k = 1;
    for j = 0:6:(6*size(data,1)-6)
        cdata(j+1:j+6,:) = data(k,i);
        k = k+1;
    end
    set(h(i),'cdata',cdata);
end

colormap(jet);
```

[image]

Credits to [Sebastian at aiZac](http://www.aizac.info/matlab-3d-bars-arrays-without-empty-elements/) for the inspiration.

Comment: no offence, but that's just the same as in my answer, just less generalized. On the other hand: looks good, I remember it was a pain to analyze the `cdata` property and fill it correctly..

Comment: @GuntherStruyf Oh yes, I thought it probably would be similar. I wasn't criticising your answer at all, it's just that I prefer to find the code that I need directly on SO rather than have to follow a link to find it.

Comment: Nice: definitely better for SO to have code than links!!